# "exception in thread main / by zero" Error

Tags: java

my perfect number program has an error "exception in thread main / by zero" can someone help me find the error

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int num = 6, sum = 0, rem = num;
    while (rem != 0) {
        rem--;
        if (num % rem == 0) {
            sum = sum + rem;
        }
    }
    if (sum == num) {
        System.out.println("It is a perfect number");
    } else {
        System.out.println("It is not a perfect number");
    }
}
```

Comment: what happens as soon as rem is 1 and you decrement it by one inside the loop?

Comment: dividing by zero, and modulo (%)  is also (kind of) a division - there is only one possible location in that code where that is being used -> `rem` must be zero when that Exception is raised

Answer (score 0):

When you call `while (rem != 0)` and if `rem == 1`, decrementing it will be 0 and therefore you can't divide then.

So change `while (rem != 0)` to `while (rem > 1)` and it should work.

**[Example](https://ideone.com/2NhaEo)**

Answer (score 0):

If you know this `%` symbol finds the reminder of the division of the left number by the right number, so you should check if any time the right number was zero it raises this error, so in your program the `rem` variable decreases before you find the reminder because of that every time in the end of the loop this error happens, so you can fix that by changing the `rem--;` statement's location to the end of the loop like this:-

```
while (rem != 0) {
    if (num % rem == 0) {
        sum = sum + rem;
    }
    rem--;
}
```

So this time the loop doesn't repeat when the `rem`s value was `0`.

Comment: but I would prefer `rem > 0` just in case somehow its value is negative

Comment: Yes you're right but I think he don't want or use negative numbers.

Answer (score 0):

In your code at the 6th time of looping the rem variable value is 1, so your while loop condition will become true.

Inside while loop the remainder variable decreased to value zero, and the code (num%rem ==0) will lead to dividing by zero error, because the %operator is finding the remainder from 2 variables and at current situation the dividend is zero. So the code will throw the divide by zero exception.

Change the while loop condition to while (rem >1)

After above mentioned changes your code looks as below.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int num = 6, sum = 0, rem = num;
        while (rem > 1) {
            rem--;
            if (num % rem == 0) {
                sum = sum + rem;
            }
        }
        if (sum == num) {
            System.out.println("It is a perfect number");
        } else {
            System.out.println("It is not a perfect number");
        }
    }
```